# Free-form text with custom SRGS based Grammar

Tags: .net, grammar, speech-recognition, context-free-grammar, sapi

I am trying to develop a Voice based application that would accept user input as speech and perform some actions based on the input. This is my first ever venture into this technology and I am learning while developing it.

I am using Microsoft SAPI shipped with dotnet 4 to recognize speech. So far, I have learned about the two types of modes it supports.

> Speech recognition (SR) has two modes of operation:
>
> - Dictation mode — an unconstrained, free-form speech
>   interpretation mode that uses a built-in grammar provided by the
>   recognizer for a specific language. This is the default recognizer.
> - Grammar mode — matches spoken words to one or more specific context-free grammars (CFGs). A CFG is a structure that defines a
>   specific set of words, and the combination of these words that can be
>   used. In basic terms, a CFG defines the sentences that are valid for
>   SR. Grammars must be supplied by the application in the form of
>   precompiled grammar files or supplied at runtime in the form of W3C
>   Speech Recognition Grammar Specification (SRGS) markup or the older
>   CFG specification. The Windows SDK includes a grammar compiler:
>   gc.exe.

So essentially, whatever words I specify with the grammar, the engine would recognize only those. But I also want to include some free form text along with the structured grammar. An example for that can be names of people. If I want to capture the name from the speech, I need to have that name specified with in the grammar, but that's not possible if the application is open for anyone to use.

Is there a way I can extract some text which is not a part of the grammar already?

How can I get the system to recognize sentences such as "My name is Gary and I am 25 years old". The name can be absolutely anything, how do I define it in my Grammar?

Answer (score 3):

You can mix dictation mode with grammar mode, see this example from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723634(v=vs.85).aspx

```
<GRAMMAR>
    <!-- command to handle first and last names with semantic properties -->
    <!-- By using semantic properties, the application can ignore all of
        the text returned, except for the text associated with the dictation
        tags' semantic properties "PID_FirstName" and "PID_LastName" -->
    <RULE ID="SubmitName" TOPLEVEL="ACTIVE">
        <P>
            my first name is
            <!-- Note the implicit maximum is only one word -->
            <DICTATION PROPID="PID_FirstName"/>
            and my last name is
            <!-- Note the implicit maximum is two words -->
            <DICTATION PROPID="PID_LastName" MAX="2"/>
        </P>
    </RULE>
</GRAMMAR>
```

Comment: Thanks, for the pointers. Although the grammar mentioned here doesn't seem to be `SRGS` compatible, but now at least I have some approach that can be considered.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [GARBAGE special rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/#S2.2.3). I'm not sure how you would then retrieve the words that matched the garbage section, but I'm pretty sure there is a way.

Let me know if you figure it out as I'm interested on the subject too :).

Comment: Garbage "works" you just cannot access the text it matched :-(