# Microsoft Speech Platform - using dictation in SRGS grammar

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am developing a C# application based on the Microsoft Speech API.
I need to manage static and free text in my application. For example, a user could say "Search file [here free dictation to let the user gives the filename]".

Based on this post ([Combine free-form dictation and semantic in a srgs grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988117/combine-free-form-dictation-and-semantic-in-a-srgs-grammar)), I tried to use the following grammar:

```
<grammar version="1.0" xml:lang="fr-fr"  mode="voice" root="toplevel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar" tag-format="semantics/1.0" >
  <rule id="toplevel" scope="public">
    <ruleref uri="#tmkAction" />
    <ruleref special="GARBAGE"/>
    <ruleref uri="#tmkItemType" />
    <ruleref uri="sapi:dictation" type="application/srgs+xml"/>
    <tag>out.SpokenText=rules.latest();</tag>
  </rule>
```

But, according to the validator, this grammar file is not correct ("Warning: Could not load external grammar 'grammar:dictation'") and does not work.

does anyone have any idea how mix free text and static grammars in Microsoft Speech Platform?

Thank you

Comment: There is no need to start a new question if the older one is on the same topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine free-form dictation and semantic in a srgs grammar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988117/combine-free-form-dictation-and-semantic-in-a-srgs-grammar)

Comment: It's not the same topic. Dictation support in Microsoft.Speech namespace is new since [Speech Platform SDK 11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd266409(v=office.14).aspx). Furthermore, grammar syntax seems to be different between System.Speech and Microsoft.Speech.

Answer (score 0):

As you use sapi namespace in the last ruleref tag, what about declaring it first: `xmlns:sapi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Speech/2002/06/SRGSExtensions`

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh362814%28v=office.14%29.aspx) can be a source of information.

I can notice that your error is about `grammar:dictation` whereas your attribute is `sapi:dictation`. I think you must make sure that your xml file is well deployed at build.

You should also make sure that you installed Speech SDK Runtime Languages from your culture; the Text To Speech one AND the Speech Recognition one. [Here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=223569&clcid=0x409)