# use regular expression in grammerbuilder in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i am using SpeechRecognizer in c# . I want to use regular expression in  grammerbuilder,here is my code.This code is not working.I want to pass any sentence example  RE must pass 'this is stackoverflow', or any  sentence or sentences.

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"[a-z\-A-Z]*");
public Form1(){
InitializeComponent();    
try{
SpeechRecognizer spec = new SpeechRecognizer();
Choices chose = new Choices();
chose.Add(reg.ToString());
GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
gb.Append(chose);
Grammar gm = new Grammar(gb);
spec.LoadGrammar(gm);
spec.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>    (sre_SpeechRecognized);
spec.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRejected);
}
```

Comment: How the above code is not working?

Comment: every time the ans is @"[a-z\-A-Z]*"

Comment: `I want to pass every word.` What do you mean by a word? Please explain more clrearly about the requirements.

Comment: I have edited my question above,i want to pass any sentence or sentences

Comment: You need to use dictation rather than an SRGS grammar.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988117/combine-free-form-dictation-and-semantic-in-a-srgs-grammar

Answer (score 0):

To allow one or more words.

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^[a-z-A-Z]+(?:\s[a-z-A-Z]+)*$");
```

I assume that the words  contain  alphabets or or `-` hyphen.

OR

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^\S+(?:\s\S+)*$");
```

`\S+` matches one or more non-space characters.